# Wordpress themes and plugins not work

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have created a Wordpress site, it's very ok on Localhost but has problems when runs on live host.

After uploading Wordpress site's folder and database, everything was ok.

But the problems happened in the first time accessing "wp-admin", in the plugins page there were some lines 
“The plugin ........... has been deactivated due to an error: The plugin does not have a valid header.”
In "appearance/themes", the information of themes was just " by anonymous". Then all plugins didn't work anymore :(

I've tried to upload a new fresh Wordpress and database, but the problems still happened.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks for any help!

Comment: what are the plugins you installed?

Comment: @roninblade ContactForm7, Custom Recent Posts Widget, Enable Media Replace, List category posts, Quick Page/Post Redirect, SUPER RESPONSIVE SLIDER, TinyMCE Advanced, wp-jquery-lightbox, WP-Mail-SMTP, WP Migrate DB and WPML Multilingual CMS.

Comment: Deactivate all plugins and then activate one at a time so you can find out which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Hey I'm facing the same issue.... If u ve got it resolved.... Cud u plz help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

in your header.php file inside the active theme folder and

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

in your footer.php file inside the active theme folder.

Not having those would stop the plugins from running correctly.